# Visual Studio no crea Vistas

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Buen día estoy trabajando en visual studio community 2022 en mvc, pero al momento en que quiero crear una vista desde el controlador el botón del mensaje me sale inhabilitado [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]